# Vue components css hierarchy

Tags: html, css, vue.js

I'm building a CSS framework to use in all my internal projects. The main file is organised as follows:

```
  @import "~normalize.css/normalize.css";
  @import "_variables.scss";
  @import "_mixins.scss";
  @import "_elements.scss";
  @import "_styledElements.scss";
  @import "_aux.scss";
  @import "_base.scss";
  @import "_composedElements.scss";
  @import "_layouts.scss";
```

In normalize.css are defined some button rules for example:

```
  button,
  input,
  optgroup,
  select,
  textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif; /* 1 */
    font-size: 100%; /* 1 */
    line-height: 1.15; /* 1 */
    margin: 0; /* 2 */
  }
```

In the file _elements.scss I have defined the default style for a button:

```
button {
      font-size: 1em;
      height: 40px;
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      background-color: $mainColor;
      color: $geophy-white;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      outline-color: $uiColor;
      border: none;
      padding: 2px 12px;
      cursor: pointer;
      border-radius: 2px;
      font-family: $condensed;

      &:hover {
          background-color: darken($mainColor, 20%);
          color: $geophy-white;
      }

      &--disable {
          opacity: 0.8;
          &:hover {
          }
      }
}
```

Everything works fine: I build my project, import the main scss file and I have all my style ready.
The problem is that if the HTML element is inside an external Vue component, normalize.css overwrite my library style. Here's an example:

External Vue component css:

[image]

Internal Vue component css:

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a problem with overriding styles in general, not Vue.js

I recommend adding a class to the button within the Vue component, and applying styles to that. Normalize and your base styles will be just that - base styles. Then your in-component styles can override what they need to.

If you're worried about conflicting class names between components simply add `scoped` in your `<style>` tag.

Comment: But why in the internal component the hierarchy works fine but in the external component does not?

Comment: @ste would you mind providing the code for the components? I only see stylesheets right now, so my aid is limited.